# Apple Keyboard visually modified gets my app rejected?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, appstore-approval

I've been reading some posts related to this issue but still i think my case is different.
I made a print-screen of Apple's iPad KB and edited that image.

With that in hand i made a custom UIView to simulate a KB with some improvements.
I don't use at all Apple's UIKeyboardView or window or anything neither any private api, just my custom UIView with som backgroung UIImage, some UIButtons on top and this thing looks close to an Apple's Kb but it isnt.

Am so rejected! or am not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sicario:

Yeah it seems that app is rejected because you have tried creating a keyboard similar to theirs.

Actually they believe that it is possible duplication of their keyboard. So it may be rejected.

Also you would have recieved an Email from Apple where in they would have specified, why the app was actually rejected.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

In case you haven't yet submitted your app on iTunes then you should not risk it because it is likely to get rejected if the interface of your keyboard looks same as their keyboard.

Comment: Which is weird because apple are quite on about apps keeping the same style. Also I'm sure the iPad at least has the built in ability to create custom keyboards (for example entering dates in the Numbers app)

Comment: Yeah you can say that is weird but somethings are not in our hand.

Comment: Couldn't it be that the particular reviewer rejected it. I've heard some reviewers are more strict than others. Try chaining the style of the keyboard so it is completely different? Then change it in an update.

Comment: May be you are right. but we cant risk it because if first time it goes to a strict reviewer then he generates a bug list or basically checklists for the bugs found and in other versions of that app the other reviewers have to atleast check for the bugs present in checklist. So it is not worth taking a risk

Comment: Then release the app without the modified keyboard (if you can and attempt to add it in an update, that way you at least have the app released)

Comment: Nope but the update or new version would be rejected. So better option is to create our own interface rather than using interface similar to Apple's compponents.

Comment: @PARTH but then you could get it rejected for not following the HIGs. But if the update only contained the keyboard it wouldn't matter. Also take wolframalpha ipad and iphone app, which has a customized keyboard http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim//2010/04/28/WolframAlpha.png

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys. I've been doing my homework and is absolutly right i will be rejected. This will be my 6th app i know how the process work but i never had to customize the kb.